# Ios menu related issue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

Since I'm new to Ios , What i wanted to is given demonstration bellow [image]

That means, on over the image and some text will remain static but , bellow a sliding menu would work like the gif.
if I tap on some menu item it will slide to bring related menu. if I press on the cross it will act back ward.
I don't even know what does it call. I tried with `customsegue` and transitions. but no luck . also tried with transparent show modally. it works for one view but not for backword (i.e. unwinding) . it get darker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using UIPageController for pagination effect.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can i hide the dots beneath? instead could i use some @IBAction to call them?